# New build notification for guests

Tags: azure-pipelines

I moved my build from `Teamcity` to the free `Azure-Pipelines`. In Teamcity there were links, you could use to subscribe to new builds. I cannot find something similar in Azure-Pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create subscriptions for the builds in Azure DevOps.

If the guests are already in a team, then just deliver the notification to team members, if the guests are not in a team you can also deliver the notifications by guests' email address.

Please see [Manage personal notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-personal-notifications?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) and [Manage notifications for a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-team-notifications?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.

Comment: To my understanding this requires knowledge of guest email, therefore is not similar to the anonymous subscription offered by an RSS, am I correct?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris Yes, it requires the guest email address, anonymous subscription by RSS is not supported.